# Logging as the caller module in Python

Tags: python, logging

I have the following application structure:

```
./utils.py
def do_something(logger=None):
    if not logger:
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    print('hello')
    logger.debug('test')

./one.py
from utils import do_something
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
do_something(logger=logger)

./two.py
from utils import do_something
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
do_something(logger=logger)
```

Now, then this runs, the logging output will show the names of the respective modules that are using the functions (`one` and `two`) rather than `utils`. I then use this information (the logger's name) to filter the messages.

Is there a way to do this without having to pass the logger though as an argument? Would I have to basically introspect the caller function and initialize a logger based on that? What's the common solution for this type of recipe, when one function is used all over the code base but the loggers should be of those calling the function?

Comment: You can do that with a ContextFilter.

Comment: I created a gist to demonstrate. Only tested in Python 3.7 so far. https://gist.github.com/rgacote/f6a3381c71f6808ebf2893793e22f3ae

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable `logger` being a global, can be accessed from inside `do_something()` function like this:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
def do_something():
    x = logger
```

---

After reading this carefully:

> What's the common solution for this type of recipe, when one function
>   is used all over the code base but the loggers should be of those
>   calling the function?

In [simple english](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page) would be:

> How to access global variable `logger` from imported function `do_something()`?

I conclude that there is no other way!
**You have to pass logger as an argument for this particular case.**

```
from utils import do_something
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

do_something()  # logger global is not visible in do_something()
do_something(logger=logger)  # the only way
```

Comment: Not sure I understand. I don't want `do_something` to be in `one.py` or `two.py`. At the same time, I want the records in logs to have the names of those files rather than `utils`.

Comment: It is not possible for an imported function to access global variables of the module where it [function] is imported.

Comment: @mart1n You have to pass logger as an argument.

Comment: Ok, passing as an argument seems to be the only way. I thought there would be a more elegant solution provided by the logging module. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Passing the `logger` as an argument looks fine to me. But if you have many calls to `do_something` then passing the same logger in each call is not only too verbose but prone to errors --you might pass the wrong logger by mistake. Also, while you do need to make `do_something` aware of the logger, doing it at the point where you are calling it probably does not make sense --you want to do something, not mess with loggers. OOP to the rescue: make `do_something` a method of a class and pass the logger when instantiating the class, then you do not need to pass it to the method.

```
# utils.py
class UsefulObject:
    def __init__(self, logger):
        self._logger = logger

    def do_something(self):
        print('hello')
        self._logger.debug('test')
```

Now in the client module you create an instance of `UsefulObject` and you can call `.do_something` on it without passing the logger every time.

```
# one.py
from utils import UsefulObject
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
useful_object = UsefulObject(logger)  # do this once
# ...
useful_object.do_something()  # do this many times, do not pass the logger
```

Comment: Great alternative! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the existing solutions, here's a magic way to do it:

```
def do_something():
    logger = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_globals['log']
    ...
```

The calling function must then have a global variable called `log`.