# Logging based on caller module

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ill start by saying that I have found the following topic : 
[Logging as the caller module in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47392917/logging-as-the-caller-module-in-python)
but it's over a year old and I was hoping something has changed.

**Short explanation:**

I have a global function used from multiple files, and I want it to log its result to the same file as the calling modules logger.

Passing the logger as an argument isn't really and option, since I have many of 
these functions.

Neither is nesting all my function under a class just in order to pass a logger instance.

**Long explanation:**

Im creating an application with a combination of flask and SQLAlchemy, with the rest requests accessing functions of the sqlAlchemy modules.
I would like the sqlAlchemy modules to print to the same log as the resource which called them.

Something like this :

1. Post request
2. Write something to some_resource.log
3. Call a function in sqlAlchemy module
4. write something to some_resource.log (From the sqlAlchemy module)

With the some_resource.log changing for every resource.

Comment: Why don’t the answers you have linked to not satisfy you, besides being one year old?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Adding a logger argument to all functions isnt the best solution, and neither is nesting all my sub class just for the purpose of a logger variable. It seems as if there should be a better solution.

Comment: I've added an answer to the linked question. In the spirit of SO I think this should probably be closed as a duplicate, since I don't think not being happy with existing answers is a good enough reason to keep this open. I will wait a bit before doing so, because my vote alone will close it. If anyone has a good reason this should stay open, speak now.